Woocommerce and flask for sending request
I am building an application for sending products into woocoomerce store. The issue I face is in sending an image with the product data from my local system.
API.post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data' - The problem
I have a code that sends the image to the woocommerce first and returns the image url and then I can send the product data with the image url. But it was not happening.
API.post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'- The error I got.
from woocommerce import API

# Setup WooCommerce API Client
wcapi = API(
    url="https://ewrererewr.com",
    consumer_key="ck_ckey",
    consumer_secret="cs_csecret",
    version="wc/v3"
)

# Image file to be uploaded
image_file_path = "path/to/image.jpg"

# Function to upload image and get the image URL
def upload_image(wcapi, image_file_path):
    with open(image_file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        response = wcapi.post("media", files={"file": image_file})
        if response.status_code == 201:
            return response.json()['source_url']
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to upload image: {response.status_code} {response.json()}")

# Function to create product with image URL
def create_product(wcapi, image_url):
    data = {
        "name": "Sasuke action figure",
        "type": "simple",
        "regular_price": "21.99",
        "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
        "categories": [
            {"id": 9},
            
        ],
        "images": [{"src": image_url}]
    }
    response = wcapi.post("products", data=data)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to create product: {response.status_code} {response.json()}")

# Main function to streamline the process
def main():
    try:
        image_url = upload_image(wcapi, image_file_path)
        print(f"Image uploaded successfully: {image_url}")
        product = create_product(wcapi, image_url)
        print("Product created successfully:", product)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


